# Installing VS2008 on a machine with VS2005 and VS2003 already installed

Tags: visual-studio

Like the title says is there any issues I should be aware of please?

Malcolm

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445472/are-there-any-known-issues-of-vs-2003-2005-and-2008-coexisting

Comment: -1 for not at least searching SO before asking this.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this without problems before. Just make sure you install them in chronological order - installing 2008 *then* 2005 can cause problems.

Just for reference, VS2010 installs side-by-side as well. I think MS realises that this is a pretty common thing to want to do :)

Comment: Can I open a application developed in .net framework 2.0 with visual studio 2008, in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: Thanks, what about upadating to SP1. Just run the upgrade no prerequisites?

Comment: @Phoenix: No, although if you haven't used any C# 3 features (most of which can still be used against .NET 2.0) you may be able to just tweak the version numbers of the project files by hand. @Malcolm: Yes, just run the service pack.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's completely all right and safe.

You may be interested in "Mixing Visual Studio versions OK" :
[Mixing Visual Studio versions OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187511/mixing-visual-studio-versions-ok)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it installed on 2 machines, and I haven't encountered any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems with this.  I installed 2003, then 2008, then 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2005 and 2008 operating side by side.  There are no issues from a usability standpoint of Visual Studio itself.  The issues tend to be more subtle.  For instance, I recently had a problem related the the ASP.NET AJAX extensions 1.0 and compatability after .NET 3.5 was installed as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617818/parse-error-while-using-scriptmanager/).